# How do I split a csv field that has quotations into two fields?

Tags: python, csv

Final Edit: It works! Thank you everyone for your assistance, and thank you especially to Padraic for helping me until I got it working.

Firstly, I apologise if this has been asked before, I did search rather extensively, but perhaps it is worded in a way I didn't expect.

So I am working with a csv file that is like this:

`0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5,21171,7.25,S`

I have to parse this file, and then write parts of it to another csv which I did with this code:

```
import csv
infile = open('data/data.csv', 'r')  
incsv = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ',')
outfile = open('data/output.csv', 'w', newline = '')
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ',')
```

The problem is that the field 'name' is formatted `"Lastname, othernames"` and I need to split that into two fields: 'lastname' and 'othernames'.

I can't seem to find a way to get it to ignore the quotations and split the names by the delimiter (','). It's a list, so .strip() doesn't work, and I haven't been able to figure out if quote_none doesn't work, or if I just don't have the syntax down.

It probably goes without saying, but I'm quite new to all of this.

**Edit: I'm getting errors with these solutions, so I'm going to include the rest of the code, in the hopes that it will highlight where things are going wrong.**

```
import csv

infile = open('data/titanic.csv', 'r')
incsv = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ',')
outfile = open('data/survivors.csv', 'w', newline = '')
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ',')

dict ={}

for row in incsv:
survived, pclass, name, sex, age, sibsp, parch, ticket, fare, cabin,    embarked = row
    if survived == "1": 
        if name not in dict:
            dict[name] = name, pclass, sex, age

names = dict.keys()
sorted_names = sorted(names)

for name in sorted_names:
    (name, pclass, sex, age) = dict[name]
rowOutput = (name, pclass, sex, age)
outcsv.writerow(rowOutput)

outfile.close()    
infile.close()
```

So this parses the original csv, filters by survived == '1', adds the names to a dict (I'm aware I will need to adjust this once I split the name field), and sorts that dictionary alphabetically.

Edit: Here is more of the original file as requested. Sorry for not including more initially.

```
survived,pclass,name,sex,age,sibsp,parch,ticket,fare,cabin,embarked
0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,,S
1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)",female,27,0,2,347742,11.1333,,S
```

that's 10 lines of 892 (891 if you don't count the header).

Comment: Is it always the same column that you need to split?

Comment: Use pandas: `import pandas; import csv; pd.read_csv('data/data.csv',header=None,sep=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` and then remove the `"` character from first and last names columns.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, it is only that one column 'name'

Comment: What are the errors? do all names actually include first and last?

Comment: @abdou that seems to shift all my column names to the right by 1. is there a way to rectify that?

Comment: @LachlanBlackmore, this can be done quite easily without pandas but unless we have some idea how you want to structure the data after you split or the errors you are getting it is impossible to answer your question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham well with Daniel's answer, I get AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'.
with TheMagician's answer I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 11)", so I added another value to my row 'lastname' and I get "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 12, got 11)
With your solution, it seems to only write the very last line to the csv.

Comment: Try, the edit to may answer, you only want the first five columns so you don't need to unpack the whole row

Comment: Also why are you checking `if name not in dict:`?

Comment: @LachlanBlackmore, I just went with the snippet of data you have on the body of your question. Without a more comprehensive amount of data, I cannot provide more.

Comment: @padraic I thought I needed to, to add it to the dict.

Comment: @LachlanBlackmore,  no, only if you were doing a lookup and did not want a KeyError if the key did not exists, not for an assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is always in the same column you can split:

```
  In [20]: s = '0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5,21171,7.25,S'

In [21]: import  csv

In [22]: row = (next(csv.reader([s])))

In [23]:row
['0', '3', 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', 'male', '22', '1', '0', 'A/5', '21171', '7.25', 'S']

In [24]: last,first = row[2].split(",")

In [25]: last, first.strip()
Out[25]: ('Braund', 'Mr. Owen Harris')
```

Presuming you jusy want to use the last name as the main key:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dct = {}

with  open('data/titanic.csv') as infile, open('data/survivors.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    incsv = csv.reader(infile)
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)
    for survived, pclass, name, sex, age in map(itemgetter(0,1, 2, 3, 4), incsv):
        if survived == "1":
            last, first = name.split(",")
            dct[last] = [first, pclass, sex, age]

    sorted_names = sorted(dct)
    for last_name in sorted_names:
         outcsv.writerow( [last_name] + dct[last_name])
```

`itemgetter(0,1,2,3,4)` pulls just the first five columns which is all we are interested in, we unpack the five value in the for loop, split the names and use the last name as the key.

If the first name can be missing you can use *str.partition*:

```
        last, _, first = name.partition(",")
        dct[last] = first.strip(), pclass, sex, age
```

The final output will be in the format:

```
last_name, other_names, plcass, sex, age
```

Output on a sample lines:

```
In [2]: cat test.csv
1,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5,21171,7.25,S
0,3,"Braund1, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5,21171,7.25,S
1,3,"Braund3, Mr. Owen2 Harris2",male,22,1,0,A/5,21171,7.25,S
0,3,"Braund2, Mr. Owen2 Harris2",male,22,1,0,A/5,21171,7.25,S
In [3]: cat survivors.csv

In [4]: paste
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
dct = {}
with open('test.csv') as infile, open('survivors.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    incsv = csv.reader(infile)
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)
    for survived, pclass, name, sex, age in map(itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), incsv):
        if survived == "1":
            last, first = name.split(",")
            dct[last] = [first, pclass, sex, age]
    sorted_names = sorted(dct)
    for last_name in sorted_names:
        outcsv.writerow([last_name] + dct[last_name])

## -- End pasted text --

In [5]: cat survivors.csv
Braund,Mr. Owen Harris,3,male,22
Braund3,Mr. Owen2 Harris2,3,male,22
```

Comment: yeah the last name as main key, sorry. I was working through trying to provide the information you needed. trying this now.

Comment: when it reached name.partition, I got this:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'partiton'

Comment: A type, run the first code block using split first, do you want a first name and last name column in the final output?

Comment: exact format I want is last name, other names, pclass, gender, age so in the example above, 
Braund,Mr. Owen Harris,3,male,22  though I just realised he was a poor example, as he would be filtered out. Same thing though,

Comment: yes, I do want a first name and last name column in the final output

Comment: Okay, this ran without any errors, however it only printed the last row, do you know why?

Comment: The only possible way that would happen would be of you either had a file with one row or all the last names were the same as dicts can only have unique keys. Do surnames repeat in your file?

Comment: well, then I'm at a loss. the file has 891 and no repeated last names.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the file? Also I presume you  have more that one  survived == "1" in the file yes?

Comment: I ran the code myself on a sample file and it does exactly what it should so are you sure you have it exactly as posted?

Comment: added a snippet to the original. I'm triple-checking I have it exactly now.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the list as you iterate through:

```
for row in incsv:
    row[2:2] = row[2].split(',')
    outcsv.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I get this: AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Sorry, should have been `writerow`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple transform function that modifies the lines before they're passed to the CSV reader

```
import csv

def transform(f):
    for line in f:
        yield line.replace('"', '')

infile = open('C:/in.csv', 'r')  
incsv = csv.reader(transform(infile), delimiter = ',')
outfile = open('C:/out.csv', 'w')
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ',')

outcsv.writerows(incsv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to subvert the csv module: you have a single field enclosed in quotation mark do read it as a single one.

But... once you have got it you can easily split it (the quotation mark have gone at that moment) and write it as two different fields in output csv file:

```
for row in in csv:
     survived, pclass, name, sex, age, sibsp, parch, ticket, fare, cabin,   embarked = row
    try:
        lastname, othernames = name.split(',', 1)
    except:
        lastname, othernames = (name, '')
    if survived == "1": 
        # ok, you can use lastname and othernames...
```